# How to check-Test value is only string/integer or alphanumeric on UnitTesting Assert

Tags: c#

Hi All I'm new in (microsoft C#) UnitTesting Assert,

I want to check UnitTesting as, Value is only string for one function,
only integer in one function and only alpha-numeric in function, which user typing in three testbox.

I have no idea of how to Test unittesting (checking) for that three scanerios.

eg
1)Textbox1 -> only allow string

2)Testbox2 -> only allow integer

3)Textbox3 -> only allow alpha-numeric

And I want to Automate Test from UnitTesting functions.

Please help!!!
sorry for my english as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a validate function for each of the rules, then unit test the function.

Then call the function in the validation of the Textbox.

You can use a RESEX expression to do the validation